# Why is SOLR Spatial Buffer returned as an Ellipse?

Tags: solr, spatial

Here is the query, lat lon are doubles (decimal degrees coordinates) passed into a method:

```
 String query = "http://myserver:8983/solr/mycore/select?&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=pointGeom_rpt&pt=" + lat + "," + lon + "&d=" + distance + "&wt=json&indent=true&geo=true&rows=" + rows;
```

the field type is RPT and I am using SOLR 4.10.0
I have tried geo=false as well, but it does not change. My goal is to get a nice round buffer (or as round as reasonable)

I have a feeling I need to do something different at index time....but can't find any info that fits my situation.
here is my field definition

```
 <field name="pointGeom_rpt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false"/>
```

and the type definition

```
 <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
        geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" units="degrees"  />
```

My return is this

[image]

This index is pretty large (250 Million entries) so I have not tried geo=true on the type definition yet and then reindexed.... hopefully someone can give me some pointers as to how to achieve round buffers and I'll get it right the first time before a massive reindex.

Comment: What is the map projection?  And is the intent to capture everything within D distance from some point, or do you instead define it as a circle on the 2D map used for display?  The latter can be a performant shortcut for the former if you use a suitable projection and if the shape in question isn't huge, but there will be some distortion. Your graphic is so distorted, that it appears to be either an inappropriate projection, or something got mis-translated between projections. Your Solr use seems fine.

Comment: @DavidSmiley thanks, I want entries D distance from a point. There are several steps that happen prior to the points getting loaded into SOLR so I will trace back through that and look for projection and transformation issues.